# How do I prove this statement about the limes of integrals?

Tags: integration, limits, sequence-of-function

I have the following problem:

> Let $f:\Omega \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be an integrable function. Show that for the functions $$g_n(x)=\log\left(1+\frac{f(x)}{n}\right)$$ we have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n\int_\Omega g_n \,d\mu=\int_\Omega f\, d\mu$$

I have just shown that $g_n$ is integrable. Now I wanted to proof the above statement as follows:

**Proof**
Let us first remark that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n\int_\Omega g_n \,d\mu=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_\Omega \log\left(\left(1+\frac{f(x)}{n}\right)^n\right) d\mu$$

Let us define now $h_n(x)=\log\left(\left(1+\frac{f(x)}{n}\right)^n\right)$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} h_n(x)=f(x)$. Furthermore we can also see that $|h_n(x)|=h_n(x)\leq f(x)$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Since $f(x)$ is integrable by assumption we can use the dominated convergence theorem and get: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_\Omega \log\left(\left(1+\frac{f(x)}{n}\right)^n\right)=\int_\Omega \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\log\left(\left(1+\frac{f(x)}{n}\right)^n\right)\stackrel{\text{$\log$ is continuous}}{=}$$ $$= \int_\Omega \log\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{f(x)}{n}\right)^n\right)=\int_\Omega f(x)\, d\mu$$

Does this work so?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Integrand convergence is pointwise.  You might check if that is enough.

Comment: sorry what do you mean? I don't get it, I think that my $h_n$ converges pointwise

Comment: Pointwise convergence is NOT sufficient for convergence of the integral.  Simple example.  $f_n(x)=n$ for $\frac{1}{n}\lt x\lt \frac{2}{n}$ and $0$ otherwise.  $\int f_n(x)dx=1$, but $f_n(x)\to   0$ pointwise.

Comment: But pointwise convergence IS sufficient to apply the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: True enough.  I missed that statement.

Comment: ah okey perfect thank you for your help!